# Spring data JPA Teradata: Conversion between BYTE data and other types is illegal

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, teradata

I am not able to insert a record into the table.

Save method

```java
@Modifying
@Query(value = "LOCKING TABLE JOB_QUEUE FOR WRITE INSERT INTO JOB_QUEUE (FILE_GUID, FILE_TYPE, PIPELINE_NAME, STATE, PRIORITY, DATE_CREATED, REQUEST_USER_ID, SPLIT_BY_BUS, FILTER_ID, GROUP_BY_BUS, RULE_SET, MAP_ID, OUTPUT_PATH, IS_REPLAY, SUBSCRIBING_PARTNER) VALUES (:#{#entity.fileGuid}, :#{#entity.fileType}, :#{#entity.pipelineName}, :#{#entity.state}, :#{#entity.priority}, :#{#entity.dateCreated}, :#{#entity.requestUserId}, :#{#entity.splitByBus}, :#{#entity.filterId}, :#{#entity.groupByBus}, :#{#entity.ruleSet}, :#{#entity.mapId}, :#{#entity.outputPath}, :#{#entity.isReplay}, :#{#entity.subscribingPartner})", nativeQuery = true)
        <S extends JobQueue> void saveJobQueue(S entity);
```

Model Class

```java
@Entity
@Table(
   name = "JOB_QUEUE"
)
public class JobQueue implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   @Column(
      name = "DATE_CREATED"
   )
   private Timestamp dateCreated;
   @Column(
      name = "FILE_GUID"
   )
   private String fileGuid;
   @Column(
      name = "FILE_TYPE"
   )
   private String fileType;
   @Column(
      name = "FILTER_ID"
   )
   private Long filterId;
   @Column(
      name = "GROUP_BY_BUS"
   )
   private BigDecimal groupByBus;
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(
      strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
   )
   private Long id;
   @Column(
      name = "IS_REPLAY"
   )
   private BigDecimal isReplay;
   @Column(
      name = "MAP_ID"
   )
   private Integer mapId;
   @Column(
      name = "OUTPUT_PATH"
   )
   private String outputPath;
   @Column(
      name = "PIPELINE_NAME"
   )
   private String pipelineName;
   private Integer priority;
   @Column(
      name = "REQUEST_USER_ID"
   )
   private String requestUserId;
   @Column(
      name = "RULE_SET"
   )
   private String ruleSet;
   @Column(
      name = "SPLIT_BY_BUS"
   )
   private BigDecimal splitByBus;
   private String state;
   @Column(
      name = "SUBSCRIBING_PARTNER"
   )
   private String subscribingPartner;
}
```

Table schema

```sql
CREATE SET TABLE JOB_QUEUE ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO,
     MAP = TD_MAP1
     (
      ID BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
           (START WITH 1 
            INCREMENT BY 1 
            MINVALUE 0 
            MAXVALUE 999999999999999999 
            NO CYCLE),
      FILE_GUID VARCHAR(250) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      FILE_TYPE VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      PIPELINE_NAME VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      STATE VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      PRIORITY INTEGER NOT NULL,
      DATE_CREATED TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
      REQUEST_USER_ID VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      SPLIT_BY_BUS NUMBER(1,0),
      FILTER_ID BIGINT,
      GROUP_BY_BUS NUMBER(1,0),
      RULE_SET VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      MAP_ID INTEGER,
      OUTPUT_PATH VARCHAR(500) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      IS_REPLAY NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0 ,
      SUBSCRIBING_PARTNER VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC)
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX JOB_QUEUE_UPI ( ID );
```

On execution I get the following exception

```
2021-08-05T00:30:15,800 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.12] [Error 3532] [SQLState 22018] Conversion between BYTE data and other types is illegal.
2021-08-05T00:30:16,465 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.12] [Error 3532] [SQLState 22018] Conversion between BYTE data and other types is illegal.
```

Comment: What is the datatype of your fileGuid? Seems it may be a byte array. If so you would either need to convert it to String on the client or load it to a BYTE/VARBYTE field in the database.

Comment: I found this happens when the string or int is null, it gets mapped to VARBINARY instead of VARCHAR/INTEGER, i am now putting empty string or 0 as default value if null. (It would be great if i can input null into database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPADTE**

Null values were getting mapped to VARBINARY its resolved using Hibernate type mappings.

```java
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("LOCKING TABLE JOB_QUEUE  FOR WRITE INSERT INTO JOB_QUEUE  (FILE_GUID, FILE_TYPE, PIPELINE_NAME, STATE, PRIORITY, DATE_CREATED, REQUEST_USER_ID, SPLIT_BY_BUS, FILTER_ID, GROUP_BY_BUS, RULE_SET, MAP_ID, OUTPUT_PATH, IS_REPLAY, SUBSCRIBING_PARTNER) VALUES (CAST(:fileGuid AS VARCHAR(250)), CAST(:fileType AS VARCHAR(100)), CAST(:pipelineName AS VARCHAR(100)), CAST(:state AS VARCHAR(100)), :priority, :dateCreated, CAST(:requestUserId AS VARCHAR(10)), :splitByBus, :filterId, :groupByBus, CAST(:ruleSet AS VARCHAR(100)), :mapId, CAST(:outputPath AS VARCHAR(500)), :isReplay, CAST(:subscribingPartner AS VARCHAR(100)))")
                .setParameter("fileGuid", new TypedParameterValue(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, entity.getFileGuid()))
                .setParameter("fileType", new TypedParameterValue(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, entity.getFileType()))
                .setParameter("pipelineName",
                        new TypedParameterValue(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, entity.getPipelineName()))
                .setParameter("state", new TypedParameterValue(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, entity.getState()))
                .setParameter("priority", new TypedParameterValue(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, entity.getPriority()))
                .setParameter("dateCreated",
                        new TypedParameterValue(StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP, entity.getDateCreated()))
                .setParameter("requestUserId",
                        new TypedParameterValue(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, entity.getRequestUserId()))
                .setParameter("splitByBus",
                        new TypedParameterValue(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, entity.getSplitByBus().intValue()))
                .setParameter("filterId", new TypedParameterValue(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, entity.getFilterId()))
                .setParameter("groupByBus", new TypedParameterValue(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, entity.getGroupByBus()))
                .setParameter("ruleSet", new TypedParameterValue(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, entity.getRuleSet()))
                .setParameter("mapId", new TypedParameterValue(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, entity.getMapId()))
                .setParameter("outputPath", new TypedParameterValue(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, entity.getOutputPath()))
                .setParameter("isReplay", new TypedParameterValue(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, entity.getIsReplay()))
                .setParameter("subscribingPartner",
                        new TypedParameterValue(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, entity.getSubscribingPartner()));
        query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: See the third comment:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62361231/spring-data-native-query-uses-varbinary-for-null-string-param

Comment: @Andrew casting as `TEXT` didn't work for me.